# Pipe gzip output to Bluetooth transfer?

Tags: pipe, bluetooth, compression, data

How do I pipe gzip output to Bluetooth transfer?

I am able to send send file over Bluetooth using this command:

```
bluetooth-sendto --device=12:23:35:96:45:45 file.tar
```

However, piping gzip didn't work for me yet.

```
gzip -fc file.tar | bluetooth-sendto --device=12:23:35:96:45:45
```